# cartodb visualization ownership transfer

Tags: carto

I have a visualization created in my cartodb personal account. Can I transfer this viz to my company's enterprise account without recreating it there?

Answer (score 2):

This is very old but nowadays you can export your map as a `.carto` file, which contains both data and map definition so it can be uploaded to any other carto instance directly.

Answer (score 0):

No direct way to do it, I think. The easiest way would be to create a new viz into your company's enterprise account and paste the same CartoCSS code. If your tables are not public, you will also need to export them from your personal account and import them into your company's account